# Como calcular el tiempo entre dos días

Tags: c#, date, algoritmos

Por ejemplo: ingreso al sistema en un dateTimePicker y coloco día 25/10/2020 a las 3:50p.m ingrese y en el otro dateTimePicker coloco día 27/10/2020 a las 8:51 p.m el total sería 65 horas con 1 minutos.

```
   DateTime start = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        DateTime end = dateTimePicker2.Value;
        TimeSpan span = end - start;
        MessageBox.Show("Probando +"+Convert.ToString(start)+"Otro +"+Convert.ToString(end));
        var hours = span.TotalMilliseconds / 60 / 60 / 1000;
        double otro = Math.Round(hours);
        MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(otro));
```

Realice, esto pero no me da resultado

El resultado me da es 65 horas, pero en realidad son 65 horas me falta el minuto

Comment: Haz una búsqueda aquí en el propio stackoverflow y encontrarás que la diferencia entre dos fechas está resuelta para distintos lenguajes de programación.

Comment: Por favor no abuses de las etiquetas

Comment: esto es c# solo me falta el minuto ahora mismo estoy llegando a 65 minutos, como puedo hacer que la variable tome los decimales?

Comment: Como puedo truncar que solo me aparezcan dos digitos luego del punto decimal?